# Getting results from database for this month, next month and last month

Tags: sql, date

I need to check the results from a query for current month, next month and last month. The query for current month is:

```
SELECT 
    Types.Type,
    (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM Pitch
         LEFT JOIN booking ON Pitch.Location_Id = booking.Location_Id
     WHERE 
         Pitch.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID
         AND (MONTH(Booking.EndDate) = month(GETDATE()) 
              OR MONTH(Booking.StartDate) = month(GETDATE()))
    ) AS total
FROM
    Types
```

I tried month`GETDATE()+1` for next month and `month(GETDATE()-1)` for last month and this also works, but only if the date does not go into next year (if I ran the query in December 2015, it wouldn't find records for January 2016).

Comment: As a note, `MONTH(GETDATE()+1)` will return the month tomorrow, not next month. You were looking for `MONTH(GETDATE())+1`. Also, doesn't your query exclude `Booking`s that are longer than 1 month? To fix that, you can simply compare so that `MONTH(Booking.EndDate) >= month(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(Booking.StartDate) <= month(GETDATE())`... I think.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Far too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the issue

```
SELECT 
    Types.Type,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(*) 
     FROM 
         Pitch LEFT JOIN booking ON Pitch.Location_Id = booking.Location_Id
     WHERE 
         Pitch.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID AND 
         (MONTH(Booking.EndDate) = month(DATEADD(MM,1,getdate())) 
          OR MONTH(Booking.StartDate) = month(DATEADD(MM,1,getdate())))
    ) AS total
FROM
    Types
```